# Select data between two dates and select only the updated date

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table employee_tbl with this data:

```
emp_no,date_posted
1,2014,08,01 
1,2014,08,02
3,2014,08,01
3,2014,08,02
5,2014,08,01
5,2014,08,02
```

i want to select the employee data where the date is between 2014,08,01 and 1,2014,08,03
so i will get them all.

```
1,2014,08,01
1,2014,08,02
3,2014,08,01
3,2014,08,02
5,2014,08,01
5,2014,08,02
```

but i only want to get the employee with the latest date like this

```
1,2014,08,02 
3,2014,08,02
5,2014,08,02
```

how will i query this one?

Answer (score 0):

please specify the query you are using.

I think you are using sqlLite
then use this one

```
SELECT date_posted,emp_no FROM employee_tbl WHERE date_posted is between 2014,08,01 and 2014,08,03 ORDER BY date_posted LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: select * from employee_tbl where date_posted is between 2014,08,01 and 2014,08,03 but i dont know how to distinct or select only the latest date posted. ex. i got 1,2014,08,01 
1,2014,08,02 but i only need this 1,2014,08,02

Comment: try this one
    SELECT column_name FROM table_name
    ORDER BY column_name DESC
    WHERE ROWNUM <=1;

Comment: if i got employee 0001 has a 3 record from my query select * from employee_tbl where date_posted is between 2014,08,01 and 2014,08,03
0001,2014,08,01 

0001,2014,08,02

0001,2014,08,03 i want to get the latest employee base on date ex. this one 0001,2014,08,03

Comment: @lolliloop have you tried my query i.e SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name DESC WHERE ROWNUM <=1;

Comment: i have two dates where i will compare it if employee is between that two?

Comment: select * from employee_tbl where date_posted is between 2014,08,01 and 2014,08,03 ORDER BY date_posted DESC WHERE ROWNUM <=1;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @CODEFISH it need atleast 50 reputation to comment on question post

Comment: In that case edit your Answer with the latest answer you have provided in comments so that it is clearly visible to any other person who have similar type of question.

Comment: please clarify your query

Comment: @GauravGupta You have two where in one query. He is concerned about that. See your comment above my first comment.

Comment: select * from employee_tbl where (date_posted is between 2014,08,01 and 2014,08,03) AND  (ROWNUM <=1) ORDER BY date_posted DESC;

Comment: what is ROWNUM? i have only emp_no and posted_date fields

Comment: ROWNUM is a pseudocolumn which indicates the row number in a result set retrieved by a SQL query. It starts by assigning 1 to the first row and increments the ROWNUM value with each subsequent row returned. A query result set can be limited by filtering with the ROWNUM keyword in the WHERE clause.
Note that a ROWNUM is not data in the database or table. It has no relationship to anything in the database, including tables, tablespaces, data files, or to the order in which a row is inserted into a table.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out rows with unwanted dates, use normal comparions (`>=`, `<=`), or BETWEEN.

To get one output row for each distinct value in a column, use GROUP BY.

To get the largest value in each group, use MAX:

```
SELECT emp_no,
       MAX(date_posted)
FROM employee_tbl
WHERE date_posted BETWEEN '2014,08,01' AND '2014,08,03'
GROUP BY emp_no
```